# pgAdmin 4 not displaying icons properly

Tags: pgadmin-4

pgAdmin4 used to display properly, but as of a month or two ago, it stopped displaying icons properly (see image below). Regular operations perform correctly, and I can still click on icons, but they aren't always easily visible. I've tried uninstalling completely and reinstalling, but it didn't help the issue. I'm using a Windows 10 x64 machine. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to latest version and check if the issue is resolved? 
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: @n33rma Thanks, patching to the April update fixed it. A few weeks ago  I was at the latest version so I didn't think to re-check.

Comment: Similar issue in PgAdmin 4 v3.4 on Firefox / Ubuntu 16: the icons are not found; instead, there are ugly little blocks.

Comment: actually it is so bad that the UI cannot be used to save a query script, for example: the field to define the script name is half hidden by the border of the containing dialog.